# Outputting directory in Gulp

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-watch

I've looked at a few other questions about Gulp, but I can't seem to pin down what's wrong with my code.

Problem: I am trying to output all of my subdirectories (of 'public') & the files within them into a new directory called 'dist'... Now when I run 'gulp' or 'gulp build' the console spits out no errors and no new directory shows up. Any help?
I'm sure it's something simple I'm not seeing.

Here's what my file tree looks like:

[image: file tree]

```
'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp'),
  concat = require('gulp-concat'),
  uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
  rename = require('gulp-rename'),
    sass = require('gulp-sass'),
    maps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');

gulp.task('concatJS', function() {
  return gulp.src(['public/js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js',
                    'public/js/Chart.min.js',
                    'public/js/constructor.js'])
    .pipe(concat('app.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public/js'));
});

gulp.task('minifyJS', ['concatJS'], function() {
  return gulp.src('public/js/app.js')
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(rename('app.min.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public/js'));
});

gulp.task('compileSass', function() {
  return gulp.src('public/scss/style.scss')
    .pipe(maps.init())
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(maps.write('./'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public/css'));
});

gulp.task('watchSass', function() {
  gulp.watch('public/scss/*.scss', ['compileSass']);
});

gulp.task('build', ['minifyJS', 'compileSass'], function() {
  return gulp.src(['css/style.css', 'img/**', 'js/app.min.js', 'index.html'], {base: './'})
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});

gulp.task('default', ['build']);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You appear to be omitting the "public/" prefix in your *build* task's `gulp.src` paths

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
gulp.task('build', ['minifyJS', 'compileSass'], function() {
  return gulp.src(['public/css/style.css', 'public/img/**', 'public/js/app.min.js', 'public/index.html'], {base: './'})
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});

gulp.task('default', ['build']);
```

Not exactly sure which directory your gulp file is in. But chances are you might be reading the wrong directory.

Comment: Wow, thank you. It works. Although, it makes another 'public' directory inside the new 'dist' directory...but other than that, it works great!

I suspected it was that, but I assumed defining /public in the other gulp tasks would carry into the body of the gulp build task.